# PCRE regex lookahead

Tags: regex, preg-match, pcre

I can't get PCRE lookahead to work correctly, help will be appreciated, I am finding it difficult to explain but here we go, take this pattern for example:

```
/^\/page(\/?[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+)*\/?$/i
```

This matches:

- /page
- /page/
- /page/abc/def/

which is good, but this also matches '/page**abcd**' which is supposed to be wrong. So basically for a URI trailing "/" should be optional unless there is some other `[a-z0-9\.\-\_]*`

I have helplessly tried `^\/page(?=(\/)(\/?[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+)*|(\/)?)$` while I knew I am doing something wrong

Comment: looks like my escape characters have been wiped out from post

Comment: Remove `?` after `(\/` - try [`^\/page(\/[a-z0-9._-]+)*\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/F6fepr/2)

Comment: Thank you joey, how you doin'?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew omg, +1, that simple... I must have been having a brain fart or something, thanks mate, stay sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enforce the presence of a letter, digit, `.`, `_` or `-` by removing the `?` quantifier after `/` inside the quantified capturing group. Also, you may use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to shorten the pattern a bit. A non-capturing group will also be more appropriate since you do not need to capture the value of a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) (replace `(` with `(?:`).

Use

```
/^\/page(?:\/[\w.-]+)*\/?$/i
            ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6fepr/4).